# What does this warning mean "Note Info: External iframes found : notfound01.domainparkingserver.net/ found near the body tag"

Tags: security, iframe, minify

A security scan comes up with this warning on a cached minify file (mywebsite/wp-content/cache/minify/000000/t.src;return)

**Note Info: External iframes found : notfound01.domainparkingserver.net/ found near the body tag on sample pages**

I can't find that minify file in my cache. Nor can I find any other reference to domainparkingserver.net in any other file on my site. Is there anything to this warning?

Answer (score 1):

The scanner you used emit a warning because iframes can be considered as a security risk.

Look at this question [Why are iframes considered dangerous and a security risk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289139/why-are-iframes-considered-dangerous-and-a-security-risk)

The warning is probably due to ShopBundle which contains the following file: [robotocondens ed-regular.html](https://github.com/Infinity-3A3/ShopBundle/blob/master/ShopBundle/Resources/public/css/fonts/robotocondens%20ed-regular.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>404 Error - Page Not Found</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
      var url = 'http://notfound01.domainparkingserver.net/?domain_name='
                + document.domain + '&a_id=101686';
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#content').attr('src', url);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="http://notfound01.domainparkingserver.net/" id="content"
            frameborder="0" height="800" scrolling="auto" width="100%">
      <!-- browser does not support iframe's -->
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Moreover the name of the file causing the warning:

```
mywebsite/wp-content/cache/minify/000000/t.src;return
```

seems abnormal and the result of a bug or a malicious request.

Comment: I understand the possible problem with iframes. I'm trying to understand if this is a real problem or if the security scan made a mistake.

I don't understand why this scan does not provide the iframe specification, but only the result - a 401 or 404 page. Is there something about a minified file that would harbor this kind of bug?

Comment: Which scanner did you use? And can you provide the minified file?

Comment: SiteLock - and I can't provide the file because SiteLock deleted it! I've rebuilt the cache and am looking for any suspicious minified files.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see anything malicious in that code - it's just a 404 error? The site I'm investigating has a cart and checkout for products, could this warning be the result of misinterpreting the code used for that commerce plugin?

Is ShopBundle malicious code?

Comment: If the filename is really `mywebsite/wp-content/cache/minify/000000/t.src;return`, this could be an indication of a bug or a malicious request, but more data (like log files) are needed for further investigations. If you think my answer is correct please click on the accept icon.