# How could I link an HTML page without creating a hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

I want to link HTML pages which I can show it directly on my webpage rather than creating a link.

Please suggest me how could I arrange it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add more details to your question, like what you are trying to achieve? What is the usecase? That way we can explain/answer in a better way. *Also, please share these details in question and not in comment.*

Comment: This is not related to Java.

Comment: #Rajesh, I want to load pages from different .html files located in my folder. For which I was using <a href="../../abc.html>ABC</a>, which hence is creating a link in my website, which I don't want. I want that the content which is in a html format to be completely shown in my website.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly it seems that you should be able to use Iframes to solve that.

`<iframe src="https://www.exampleURL.com"></iframe>`

More info can be found https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: Please explain your approach. An answer should address reason and sample. Just sharing a link with syntax is not a good answer

Comment: Please don't use or recommend or link to w3schools.

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V Please maintain SO's discipline. Comments are for queries/suggestions but the tone should be maintained. If you think something is wrong, highlight it, so that fellow devs and OP can learn from it

Comment: <iframe> is creating a box like structure that I don't want, how can I remove the box, if you can help me out that will be very helpful for me?

Comment: add frameBorder="0" to the iframe as a property like this <iframe src="https://www.exampleURL.com" frameBorder="0"></iframe>

Comment: @AdamLagevik, thank you for your help. As I want to use <iframe> to link the header & footer .html file like this <iframe src="../../header.html" target="_top"></iframe> but clicking the links on the header & footer it is opening in the<iframe> area only. In this case which syntax should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) tag in order to embed other websites into your own site.

However, please consider that this method has many vulnerability and is risk to use.

See this additional information.

[Cross Frame Scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_Frame_Scripting)

[Why are iframes considered dangerous and a security risk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289139/why-are-iframes-considered-dangerous-and-a-security-risk)