# Adding Spring Session JDBC to my Spring Boot project breaks authentication in an iframe

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

I am currently building a Spring Boot web application (2.3.1, but the following issue also was observed with versions 2.1.7 and 2.1.5) that is secured with Spring Security. I mostly use default settings (e.g. embedded Tomcat, embedded H2 database, Spring Web-MVC). I do some custom authentication on a permissive `POST` mapping with the following code:

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = ...;
SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
context.setAuthentication(authentication);
```

This works fine. Since I want to use it for student examinations, I want to persist the session with the authentication, so in case the server software would crash or go down for some reason, no one needs to re-authenticate when the server comes up again.

I used Spring Session JDBC for this. I added the following dependency to my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and the following line to my `application.properties`

```
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
```

This all works fine when I test locally. I see the sessions appearing in my database and everything works great. However, in practice the application is started from an `iframe`: a learning management system does an LTI-launch, which is a POST request of which the response ends up in the `iframe`. When I attempted to do a test deployment, I got a `403` error that my request was not Authenticated. After a frustrating day of debugging, I ultimately was able to pin down this issue to the fact that adding `spring-session-jdbc` to my project causes the web application to send a new session ID cookie on each request of the `iframe`. If I repeat the same requests without the `iframe`, the same application works fine. If I remove the `spring-session-jdbc` dependency, the application works fine within the `iframe` as well.

If I perform the authentication within the iframe, I see the following in the Spring Security debug logs (exec-1 is where a succesful authentication happens, exec-2 is the request the iframe performs after being redirected by the exec-1 request):

```
2020-06-24 22:14:02.015 DEBUG 7474 --- [nio-8031-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@671fa7ec
2020-06-24 22:14:02.015 DEBUG 7474 --- [nio-8031-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2020-06-24 22:14:02.063 DEBUG 7474 --- [nio-8031-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2020-06-24 22:14:02.113 DEBUG 7474 --- [nio-8031-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /launch/development at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2020-06-24 22:14:02.113 DEBUG 7474 --- [nio-8031-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /launch/development at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2020-06-24 22:14:02.114 DEBUG 7474 --- [nio-8031-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2020-06-24 22:14:02.114 DEBUG 7474 --- [nio-8031-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
```

When I perform the same requests with the same running application in a regular browser window, the Spring Security debug logs show the following:

```
2020-06-24 22:18:10.518 DEBUG 7474 --- [nio-8031-exec-5] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@671fa7ec
2020-06-24 22:18:10.518 DEBUG 7474 --- [nio-8031-exec-5] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@e1239cdc: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@e1239cdc: Principal: testuserid; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_INSTRUCTOR' stored to HttpSession: 'org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper$HttpSessionWrapper@66670854
2020-06-24 22:18:10.536 DEBUG 7474 --- [nio-8031-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2020-06-24 22:18:10.536 DEBUG 7474 --- [nio-8031-exec-5] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2020-06-24 22:18:10.590 DEBUG 7474 --- [nio-8031-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /home at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2020-06-24 22:18:10.591 DEBUG 7474 --- [nio-8031-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /home at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2020-06-24 22:18:10.592 DEBUG 7474 --- [nio-8031-exec-6] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@82a4fa0f: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@82a4fa0f: Principal: testuserid; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_INSTRUCTOR'
```

To me this seems rather odd: if this is purely a browser problem, it should not matter whether I use `spring-session-jdbc`. If it is a problem with how `spring-session-jdbc` stores my authentication, it should not matter if it happens in an `iframe` or not. Is there something I am missing here? Did I stumble on a bug?

I could try a workaround where I use some javascript inside the iframe to let the POST happen in a blank tab, but that feels rather ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I would advise you against using your appication in an iframe.
This poses a security risk, which you can read more about in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9428051/11430047).

Now to explain the behaviour you are seeing.
Spring Security uses a `Session` cookie to store the user's session.
Cookies are associated with domains, so if, for example, there is a cookie associated with the domain `stackoverflow.com` then that cookie will be included in any request to `stackoverlow.com`.

In order to control that behaviour, cookies also have an attribute called `SameSite`.
The [`SameSite` attribute](https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/) can have 3 values, `None`, `Lax` or `Strict`.
When the value is `None`, it behaves as described above (included in all requests).
When the value is `Lax`, then the cookie will only be included in top level navigation `GET` requests.

When including the Spring Session dependency, the `Session` cookie `SameSite` attribute is set to `Lax` by default.

Since rendering an application in an iframe is not a top level navigation, the `Session` cookie is not included in the request to the iframe, and the application has no way of knowing that a user is signed in.

You can explicitly set the `SameSite` attribute to `None` by using Spring Session.
Again, I would caution against this, since it can make your application vulnerable to CSRF and clickjacking attacks.
If, after consider the security implications, you deem it necessary to set the `SameSite` attribute to `None`, you can do so by including Spring Session in your dependencies and creating a [custom `CookieSerializer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html5/guides/java-custom-cookie.html#custom-cookie-spring-configuration).

Comment: Thank you so much for this clear answer, it is now clear to me what was going on! I noticed the SameSite attribute in the cookies while debugging, but did not pay enough attention to it. The option to use a custom CookieSerializer indeed provides a trade-off I can work with. Unfortunately, the iframe is not something that I can get rid of in the short term, but it is worthwhile to investigate the alternatives for the future.