# Getting the full URL from iframe

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, iframe

We have an iFrame on our website which is pulling in a help section from a different website.

When the iframe loads on my site you get a search box and a list of quesitons, ( the help document is a large FAQ )

When the page loads it's www.mydomain.com/help/

When you click an FAQ example : Q: How do I create an account ? 
The answer appears on the side. The URL stays the same. We want it so the URL updates to include the url of the questions example 
Once clicked URL appears as www.mydomain.com/help/how-to-create-an-account

I've checked the they do have full URL's on the main site ( help docs site )

I was reading this [deep linking to embedded iframe content in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459623/deep-linking-to-embedded-iframe-content-in-wordpress)

But not sure what inner / outer refer to. I've never heard of deep linking but this appears to be what I need.

There's no point putting up code in this instance as it's only an iframe link.

Comment: I don't think you would wanna go this route. Why are you using iframes to load FAQ pages, and not just serving it directly?

Comment: These FAQ's are coming from a network of sorts. We are not the only ones using them. We could host them locally but anytime they where updated we'd have to update them.