# IFrames and Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe

I have a menu iframe and a body iframe setup.  In IE when I click the "back" button in the menu it goes back just fine.  In chrome it works fine for the most part but there is one instance of that link that will open it in a new page even though it is a replica of other working instances of that back button.

Any ideas of what would prevent a link from working in chrome, a link that works just fine in firefox and IE?

I have a body iframe and a menu iframe.

the menu has links...some of them are targeted at the menu...the new page will redirect the body on load.

sometimes the menu link just updates the body as it doesn't need a menu.

in IE it works great.  Firefox and Chrome do not like it.  It will work fine the first time.  But when you go back and click the link that JUST worked...it will open up in a new tab instead.

New Info:

I did a bunch of research on the issue and apparently
 it's a chrome and ff update that is trying to disable iframes.  I have yet to find a solution...if you have one let me know!

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I'm just trying to offer some suggestions to you. Your question is unclear and I don't understand it. You might need to revise the wording or provide more context. Also, there are some drawbacks to using `iframe` including navigation issues so you may want to reconsider using them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/are-iframes-considered-bad-practice/362743#362743, also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081315/why-developers-hate-iframes

Comment: I have no choice in the matter since I'm contracted to work on this pre constructed web application.  Also if I knew more about the situation I may not even have to ask a question =P