# How to make my iFrame code work for mobiles too?

Tags: html, iframe

this is my first post here, and I hope I'm lucky to finaly get an answer after hours of seaching for this problem :/

I'm using a simple HTML iFrame code:

```
<iframe src="http://WEBSITE-HERE.com" style="border:0px #FFFFFF none;" name="myiFrame" scrolling="no" frameborder="1" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

It works OK with desktop browsers, but when a mobile visitors goes to the link, they get promted to download some file and the link doesn't load at all.
Is there any way I could make it work for mobile visitors too? (Link was visited from Samsung Galaxy S3)

Comment: What link are you referring to? Do you mean when a mobile device loads the page containing the iframe it prompts a download?

Comment: Yes, exactly.
The "http://WEBSITE-HERE.com" is a different website, from the one where the code is being stored (it's like I'm trying to iFrame another website, in another website) both loading at the same page.
But when a mobile user comes, I get promoted to download something like: Mobogenie ..

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively you can use `jQuery/AJAX` to load the page in a `div` instead of `iframe`:

```
$('#w_oContainer').load('page.htm');
```

CSS or script doesn't require reference to apply/communicate, and give better UX over iframe. Here is more elaboration: ([Reasons for not using IFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252349/reasons-for-not-using-iframe))

Comment: First, thanks for your answer. But could u please tell me what I exactly need to do,how the code should look, cause I'm a begginer in this field...
Thank you

Comment: Add `jQuery` in your `<head>` section of page (e.g. `<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.min.js"></script>`), then simply write the above syntax. `#w_oContainer` is your `div` id. jQuery library can be download from - http://jquery.com/