# iFrames bad or good?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, iframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are iframes considered 'bad practice'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/are-iframes-considered-bad-practice)

Some say that iFrame is evil.

But it seems that Facebook uses iFrames for the Facebook applications, and dumping FBML (Facebook markup language).

I have never used iFrames before, but is it a good practice to use them if you want to "install" other web applications on your web application.

Also, how do you send data between iFrame applications and your own web application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/are-iframes-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iframes are not evil.

They're not very well thought of, that's true, but they're not evil either. They can be misused but what technology can't?

You can send data between iframes and your own webapp with a bit of JavaScript. I think window.parent is what you're looking for.

Comment: I agree with this. Many places use iFrames for evil purposes (such as framing a site that they linked to); however, overall, they are just fine to use.

Comment: Although one thing you want to avoid is using frames in such a manner that the content of the site is in the frame and a menu is outside of the frame. Although this may seem convienient, all of your pages become unbookmarkable.