# Why wouldn't this jquery load work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load

This is not loading the website that I wanted.

```
$('#example').load("http://www.example.com");
```

http://www.jsfiddle.net/JFdVv/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't load content from a domain other than the one you're on unless it's JSONP (JSON with a function wrapper)...you can't load plain HTML like you're trying, it's blocked for security reasons by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

---

As an aside, the reason you get an error with `example_ajax_request` inline in the page is that by default jsfiddle puts your JavaScript code in a wrapper...you need to have functions like that directly in the page (global functions, not scoped to a ready handler), notice the first drop down up top...it needs to be `"no wrap"` (either one), instead of `"onDomReady"`.

Comment: @getaway - You can't do this in JavaScript directly...you could proxy the content through the domain you're on, but no other option that that for fetching non-JSONP content.

Comment: oh okay, how about if i wanted to load an iframe then, or if its a subdomain

Comment: @getaway - subdomain also is blocked, iframe would look something like this: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/JFdVv/2/

Comment: oh okay thanks, i can mark you as the right answer when it lets me :)), can i also ask you know when i load the iframe, the browser is still reloading, is thier anyway to remove that, i would rather have a my own loading bar on the page. if you get what i mean, so it makes it look instant lol :))

Comment: @getaway - you can add your own animations, but you can't remove the built-in loading indicators of the browser...they're there *somewhat* for security purposes as well, alerting the user something's happening.

Comment: @getaway - I agree, iframes are always a messy approach...you'd be better off proxying the content as far as looks go, but it's not the best practice, since you're taking their content out of context.  Something like a lightbox plugin to show the content works with a clear distinction though.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must load a page from different website, you can always use an `<iframe>` although this practice would be questionable to say the least.

Or, for a server-side solution, if you're using PHP, you can have a look at the [PHP cURL library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Comment: is using an iframe a bad practice?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/are-iframes-considered-bad-practice) should give you a much more insightful answer on that. However, when I said that I was referring to loading a full page from another domain, like in your example.