# W3C validation errors with embedded google map

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe

All the pages on the site I am designing are valid XHTML 1.0 Strict except for the home page which has a Google map link generated from My Maps

```
 <div  id="map">
 <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zBNEhg5_DRUg.ke97rR7SIh5I" width="320" height="240"></iframe>    
 </div>
```

The errors are:

```
there is no attribute "src"
there is no attribute "width"
there is no attribute "height"
element "iframe" undefined
```

Some of the articles I have read suggest replacing these with alternatives, but I'm not sure how.

Is there a reason not to use the map generator in Google?

Answer (score 0):

To validate a google embedded map you need to not use an `<iframe>`, that isn't allowed in XHTML Strict.  Instead use an `<object>` (reference: [Why won't `<iframe>` elements validate in HTML 4.01?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873502/why-wont-iframe-elements-validate-in-html-4-01)) and instead of `src` (which isn't supported), use `data`.

[example that valids XHTML Strict 1.0](http://www.geocodezip.com/example_embedded_map_W3C_XMLstrict.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>example embedded map</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <object width="600" height="450" style="border:0" data="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=API_key&amp;origin=Bern&amp;destination=Bern&amp;waypoints=Paris%7CBerlin%7CRome"></object>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```