# How do I load an url in iframe with Jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe, load

I want to load an iframe on click, this is what I have so far:

```
$("#frame").click(function () { 
      $('this').load("http://www.google.com/");
    });
```

It doesn't work. This is the complete code: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/omaxox/edit#javascript,html,live)

Comment: Do you really have to use iframes ? I am sure someone will help you how to get this done, but you should avoid iframes as much as you can.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/are-iframes-considered-bad-practice/362743#362743

Comment: I really need to use iframes:)

Comment: Alright then, I just mentioned so that you are doing it right, glade you found the right answer.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

```
$("#button").click(function () { 
    $("#frame").attr("src", "http://www.example.com/");
});
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="mydiv">
     <iframe id="frame" src="" width="100%" height="300">
     </iframe>
 </div>
 <button id="button">Load</button>
```

Comment: Cross Browser restrictions wont let you do this.

Comment: how would you gracefully handle errors? For example we have a report engine that generates a PDF document which we load into a hidden iframe which should automatically get the user to download it, but there's the possibility that something will go wrong and we'd like to notify the user of the problem.

Comment: @Jacques: Write your own logic for your custom requirements. Above answer is perfect for OP's question.

Comment: @Jacques How did you solve that problem ? I'm facing the same issue you've described

Comment: @JasonKrs Unfortunately I don't recall since this was quite a while ago. Sorry I can't be of any help.

Comment: @Jacques ouch... It's bugging me right now... Thank though

Comment: @Dogbert I saw that answer already... I think since my frame is hosted on an Apache server, it is loaded with the 404 page... So, if the resource on the remote server is not yet available, I still get some content in `load`... Also, CORS blocked from exploring the Ajax features .... Still working on it...

Answer (score 10):

Try `$(this).load("/file_name.html");`. This method targets a local file.

You can also target remote files (on another domain) take a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: The "this" in his phrase refers to the domain "www.google.com"

Answer (score 9):

```
$("#frame").click(function () { 
    this.src="http://www.google.com/";
});
```

Sometimes plain JavaScript is even cooler and faster than jQuery ;-)

Comment: Yes, please explain what "this" is in this context.

Comment: @AlexGrande "this" is the same as in the question - the iframe you are clicking on. I am answering a specific question, and in this context the only element present is the iframe.

Comment: sorry, I was referring to the highest of the answers indeed.

Comment: can we send header in calling urls? i have server side php rest that return report as html for clients. this is strange but i want to send jwt as header in calliing this page . i want to open this page as iframe in webkit. can i attach jwt to header?

Comment: yet, you just used jQuery

Comment: @OmarNShamali lol I didn't, someone decided to edit the post. As for "just", that was years ago ;-)

Answer (score 5):

here is Iframe in view:

```
<iframe class="img-responsive" id="ifmReport" width="1090" height="1200" >

    </iframe>
```

Load it in script:

```
 $('#ifmReport').attr('src', '/ReportViewer/ReportViewer.aspx');
```

Answer (score 1):

*Just in case anyone still stumbles upon this old question:*

The code was theoretically almost correct in a sense, the problem was the use of $('this') instead of $(this), therefore telling jQuery to look for a  tag.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#frame").click(function () { 
    $(this).load("http://www.google.com/");
  });
});
```

The script itself woudln't work as it is right now though because the load() function itself is an AJAX function, and google does not seem to specifically allow the use of loading this page with AJAX, but this method should be easy to use in order to load pages from your own domain by using relative paths.