# Sagepay / codeigniter / iFrame

Tags: php, codeigniter, iframe, opayo

I am really struggling to find any working examples of how to embed the Sagepay payment forms within an Iframe on my own site. I am aware that this is possible but the Sagepay doucmentation is very poor as they like to keep things "generic". Any examples in PHP/Codeigniter would be appreciated. Please note that I do not wish to store any card details etc which is why I want to use the sagepay server option.

Has anyone managed to get an iframe with the sagepay screen inside it.

This is so frustrating

Regards

James

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177080/how-do-i-load-an-url-in-iframe-with-jquery

Comment: Thanks, its the specifics about Sagepay and Iframes, that I need help on.

Comment: Well all you need to do is load their page in the iFrame? Do you have any code or errors to post? Or are you expecting someone to post their way of doing it?