# load data of page in URL using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an HTML page which I want to load on a click of a class using JavaScript. I am thinking of fetching that HTML using an iframe. This page contains content in the form of an overlay.

I have used `.load()` function of jQuery but it does not do anything. The pages I am working are both in same domain so I was hoping that the page would have loaded.

How can I achieve this?

```
$(".popup-layout").click(function() {

// I want to load an iframe here. Where should that iframe sit on the current page with diplay:none.




    });
```

Comment: can you post your markup? or a fiddle would be nicer

Comment: I was hoping that on click of the class .popup-layout, i fetch the page localhost:8080/abc.html using javascript. I have got just this javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I load an url in iframe with Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177080/how-do-i-load-an-url-in-iframe-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use ajax loaded content over an iframe, just my opion though.

```
$(".popup-layout").click(function() {
       $.get("yourFile.html", function(data){
        $("#Content").html(data); // the div to load content in
       });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#result')` is an `<iframe id='result'>`? You can't populate an iframe via jquery.load(). In fact, you don't need to. You can use a simple `<div id='result'>`

Comment: actually you can. using `.attr()`

Comment: You mean setting the src attribute of the iframe? Of course you can do that, but that has nothing to do with jquery.load()

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 methods that can help you achieve that:

1. Load the page on an `<iframe>` by changing its `src`. [Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arielnmz/6Eb2q/):

   ```
   YourFrameId.src = 'http://example.com';
   ```
2. Load the page via an `HTTP request` and change the `innerHTML` of an existent element. [Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arielnmz/GWC3P/):

   ```
   var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   req.open('GET', 'http://www.mozilla.org/', true);
   req.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
       if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
           YourElementId.innerHTML = req.responseText;
       }
   };
   req.send(null);
   ```
3. Use the `location` attribute of the `document` object:

   ```
   document.location = 'http://example.com'
   ```