# Load iframe when user clicks on modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page within my website which has about 60 iframe elements inside it. These iframes are contained within w3-modals divs but are all being loaded as soon as the page loads, causing the page to load very slowly. Is it possible when a user clicks on the button to load the w3-modal that they iframe can be loaded then to help page load time.

Any help would be much appreciated with this! But if possible please keep it simple as I am new to coding.

Thanks very much!

Here is the code Im using:

**Button to load modal**

`<button onclick="document.getElementById('id03').style.display='block'" class="w3-btn  w3-light-blue">Instruction</button>`

**Modal code**

```
<div id="id03" class="w3-modal">
      <iframe src="http://" frameborder="0" height="700px" style="width: 800px">
```

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177080/how-do-i-load-an-url-in-iframe-with-jquery) will help you. That issue looks like same.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are taking this to the incorrect way. Loading 60 different pages is crazy, and for sure your computer and browser are suffering with this.

I think a better approach would be (as you said) loading your iframes as they are requested. I'm assuming that all your iframes are hidden (and [you are using this modal system](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_modal.asp)), so we could do something like this:

```
<button class="w3-btn w3-light-blue" data-open-modal="id03">Instruction</button>
<div id="id03" class="w3-modal" data-url="your-iframe-url"></div>
```

You first defined a `button` with the data-attribute `data-open-modal` which indicate that this button will open a modal. Next, you have your modal `div` with `data-url` defining the URL to use in the iframe. So, this is the JavaScript to do the trick (with jQuery, sorry no time of vanilla):

```
// We find all the buttons 'data-open-modal'
$('[data-open-modal]').click(function (e) {
    // We get the ID of the modal to open
    var modalId = $(this).data('open-modal');
    // We set a modal reference (shortcut)
    var $modal = $(modalId);
    // We get the iframe URL from the modal data-url
    var iframeURL = $modal.data('url');
    // We show the modal
    $modal.display(); // display: block;
    // We create the iframe inside using the URL
    $modal.append('<iframe src="' + iframeURL + '" frameborder="0" height="700px" style="width: 800px">');
    // We bind a click event when the user clicks on the "X" to close the modal and whe delete the iframe
    $modal.find('.w3-closebtn').on('click', function (e) {
        $modal.find('iframe').remove(); // Delete the iframe
    });
});
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should work!

Answer (score 0):

```
var your_source = $('#source').val();
$("#button").click(function () { 
      $("iframe").attr("src", your_source);
});
```

Comment: Please describe what this is doing and why you chose to do it in this manner so you can help educate your readers.