# How to embed iFrame with external website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am learning web development and trying to achieve task of adding external webpage to a simple HTML page. So, I have a text box where I need to put the URL and based on that the iframe should render.
Webpage renders properly when `src` attribute is loaded directly using `.attr` property of `jquery`.

Working example without the text field:

**HTML**

```
<div id="mydiv">
     <iframe id="frame" src="" width="100%" height="300">
     </iframe>
 </div>
 <button id="button">Load</button>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button").click(function () { 
    $("#frame").attr("src", "https://www.wikipedia.org/");
});
});
```

Below is what I want

**HTML**

```
Enter the URL
    <input id="url" type="text"/>
      <div id="mydiv">
             <iframe id="frame" src="" width="100%" height="300">
             </iframe>
         </div>
         <button id="button">Load</button>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function () { 
    var x = $("#url").val();
        $("#frame").attr('src', 'x');
    });
});
</script>
```

I referred this [SO LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177080/how-do-i-load-an-url-in-iframe-with-jquery) but could not find the answer. My JSfiddle novice attempt tells an error message as `{"error": "Please use POST request"}`. Do I need to use `load` jquery method. I just want to read the content of textbox and open the page in iframe with a buttons click. [Link to my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d0nqj9pm/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try this simple example - I've defaulted the input to `https://en.wikipedia.org` but you can try other URLs in there.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function () { 
      var url = $('#url').val();
      $("#frame").attr("src", url);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">
    <input id="url" type="text" value="https://en.wikipedia.org"/>
     <iframe id="frame" src="" width="100%" height="300">
     </iframe>
 </div>
 <button id="button">Load</button>
```

Comment: Gawd! I added extra quotes for the variable. Thank you so so much! :)

Comment: Guys, it wont work for many sites. Most site has option `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` set already.