# Unable to view all the information in the window on viewport

Tags: popup, extjs4, viewport

I've Tabpanel in viewport layout, In tabpanel panel I want to display Extjs Window. This popup window may contains large data.If the popup height exceeds the viewport height I'm unable to view all the information in the window. So when the popup height is more then the viewport height I should view the popup content by viewport scrolling(not by popup window scrolling).

Check these screens shots to understand my issues.

A. When the popup information is less it looks like this

[image: popup with less data]

B. When the popup information is too large it looks like this

[image: Popup with large data]

Sample popup code

```
 var my_popup = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    autoHeight: true,
    //id: 'my_popup ',
    closeAction: 'hide',
    y: 50,
    frame: false,
    border: false,
    modal: true,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    plain: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    maximizable: true,
    items: content_form
});
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving that center panel (area to the right of the tree) a layout of it's own, other than the default viewport layout? Something like [anchor layout](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Anchor) with an `anchorSize` config specified.

If that wont work you could always make the center an iframe which does not contain a viewport. And then make your pop-up show from the iframe page - as long as [using iframes doesn't rest too heavily on your conscience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/are-iframes-considered-bad-practice).