# Why AJAX over iFrames?

Tags: html, ajax, post, iframe

I am relatively new programmer, talking with a partner he told me, that before AJAX, he used a iframe to send data and change the  content(obviously with help of JavaScript).

I understood that both are  similar techniques, but i didn't find a article to describe their characteristic,

what are advantages of AJAX  over Iframe ?

**EDIT**
 i didnt find any explanation of the technique, but my partner told me he post the data trough a hidden iframe and submit the iframe, sound like just the iframe have to be refreshed, but i never did that

Comment: Iframes make it easy to upload files as part of the AJAX request. Otherwise they don't offer much advantages as such.

Comment: @techfoobar ok but, i would like see a explication of both techniques, maybe in some cases is better use Iframes

Comment: The last time I used an iFrame for this was in 2004! Like @techfoobar said, it makes it a lot easier for uploading files since your post will be synchronous, but for other things such as load information on the screen, AJAX does the job better if implemented correctly. With AJAX you don't have to post full pages to get just a couple of things to show on your main view, and you don't have to write extra code to pick up elements from a document in the iFrame.

Comment: As they have said, AJAX allows for updates and sends without full page post backs. Using an iFrame even the smallest of changes requires a full page post back. Think of it in terms of forms you have used on websites. A site that has a login on a side bar in a main page that posts back the full page is most likely using an iFrame. If you login and the login disappears and has your account info but didn't have to refresh the entire page thats probably AJAX. In most cases AJAX is better because you want to keep processing as small as possible. Its better to render a small portion than a full page

Comment: well, i didnt find any explanation of the technique, but my partner told me he post the data trough a hidden iframe and submit the iframe, sound like just the iframe have to be refreshed, but i never did that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are iframes considered 'bad practice'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/are-iframes-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. One advantage AJAX has is being able to read the state/status of the
   request. You also have access to page headers, which you don't with
   Iframes.
2. Ajax can handle multiple asynch requests. It's a little trickier
   with Iframes as you need to create an Iframe per request (and keep
   track of all of them to delete them later) instead of recycling the
   same one.
3. Existing libraries are full of AJAX goodness and there is a larger community support base.

Comment: I think what @rob-sedgwick mentioned should also be noted here: CSS styling of the page will only apply to content loaded via AJAX. When you load content via an iFrame you have to include your styles again there..

Answer (score 7):

```
iframe
```

is a way show **seperately** two (or more) webpages in one

```
 ajax
```

is a way to **merge** two (or more) webpages ( or new data ) **into** one

key advantages to Ajax I find are;

- CSS will flow to the page called into it.
- A way to retrieve data and update new information to the visitors without page refresh.

A fab mention to this site for it's clever use of Ajax.

A'Google instant' and suggestive searching is achieved via Ajax

Answer (score 3):

Just my two cents:

I agree with Kris above that I wouldn't say they are comparable.

There's on use case that I find iFrames to be easier to work with over AJAX and that is if you need to submit a complicated form to another page but you don't need any response - the iframe route is by far the easiest to code.

Beyond that, AJAX, using a metaphor, acts a very knowledgeable go-between.  It will handle multiple requests, the status of those requests, and hand back the data in the format you need.

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to add this because I didn't see in any of the answers.

The reasons to use Ajax are mostly about control, which you get a lot of.  These reasons have been mentioned above.

One serious downside of Ajax, though, is that it is a JS fix.  JavaScript is a great language, but people have been throwing it at every problem for a while now, and things which could be optimized if they were built in to the browsers, are now instead being done slowly (compared to compiled languages) with JS.

iFrames are a great example of this.  They represent an incredibly common use case, wanting to include some html in some other html.  Unfortunately, they aren't very amazing at it, often creating more headache than anything else.

If you want to include something and not have it mess with your site, nor your site to mess with it, iFrames are great.  For the more common use case of including some random html in some other html, Ajax is better.

And here is the point I'm trying to make: this is dumb.  There is no reason there shouldn't be something like an iFrame that acts more like Ajax.  But, by jumping on board (as all of us did) with Ajax, we are now left with no choice.

The biggest reason this is a problem is that JS was never meant to be the absolute building blocks of the internet.  Further, it's being used by pretty much every site around to violate user privacy.  So, if you're looking for a good reason to use iFrames, this is mine:

It feels good to not need JS.  If you can make your site *improved* by JS rather than **dependent** on it, that's a hard earned accomplishment, and the site will feel less "hacky" overall.

Anyways, that's just my input.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience data loaded via AJAX is easier to manipulate versus data inside an iFrame. Also AJAX is really good for creating a better user experience. However I am not sure if I would necessarily put iFrames and AJAX in the same category because AJAX is asynchronous content and an iFrame is really just another page being loaded from outside of your site.

Also I could see iFraming creating SEO barriers and creating bad user experience. Honestly though if I had access to content I would prefer AJAX.

Comment: Usually the iframe is hidden and, before AJAX, it was common to use it to retrieve data from the server without a reload. The contents of the Iframe was grabbed by JavaScript residing in the main page. HTML was to be inserted into the DOM, via JS, or executed against the parent page if it was a JS block.