# Javascript iframe having no border

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am a coder with little expierience with css and javascript. Thanks for your help

I am trying to make my javascript create an iframe with another part of my website in it and that is working fine with this code:

```
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
    ifrm.setAttribute("src","http://www.example.com");
    var scwid = (screen.width)*(78.8/80)
    ifrm.style.width = (scwid + "px");
    ifrm.style.height = "100px";
    document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
</script>
</div>
```

That made an iframe, but iframes, in their natural state are ugly and the border is annoying. So I went online to find the css way to remove an iframe, and it said`frameBorder = "0"` would work. I tried several variations to try and add this into my script with no luck

Test #1

```
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
    ifrm.setAttribute("src","http://www.example.com");
    var scwid = (screen.width)*(78.8/80)
    ifrm.style.width = (scwid + "px");
    ifrm.style.height = "100px"
    ifrm.style.frameBorder = "0";
    document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
</script>
</div>
```

Test #2

```
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
    ifrm.setAttribute("src","http://www.example.com");
    var scwid = (screen.width)*(78.8/80)
    ifrm.style.width = (scwid + "px");
    ifrm.style.height = "100px";
    ifrm.setAttribute("0")
    document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
</script>
</div>
```

Obviously neither of these worked, so how would I do this? Put CSS in another part of my website? (As I said before, Im bad with css) Or try some other javascript altogether?

Comment: Is this what you are trying to achieve: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/au5ycf6d/1/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove border from IFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65034/remove-border-from-iframe)

Comment: If the content you want to place in the iFrame is from your own site, can you not rather use AJAX? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656992/why-ajax-over-iframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this to your CSS to get rid of frame border.

```
iframe{
border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an attribute 'frameborder' to the iframe, and set its value equal '0'.

exp:

```
<iframe frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: I want JS, not html

Comment: ifrm.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");

Answer (score 0):

you just need to set attribute  **frameBorder=0.** 
or
You can use **style="border:0;"** in your iframe code. 
and
In **HTML 5** 
you can use the seamless attribute like

Answer (score 0):

you can add css property like

```
iframe{ border:none; *\or maybe '0'*/}
```

or you can add `<iframe src="#" frameborder='0'></iframe>` in html

Answer (score 0):

Only JavaScript:

```
ifrm.frameBorder = 0;
```