# Why does frame use scrollbar?

Tags: html, iframe, scrollbar

I have a webpage which contains a frame. The frame displays a scrollbar, why?

The code for the file that contain the frame:
[enter link description here](http://denis.dk/index.txt)

The code for the file that the frame display:
[enter link description here](http://denis.dk/startside.txt)

The webpage is [this](http://denis.dk/)

The problem: I would like to show the whole page without the scrollbar, so that the main page scroll then you would like to see the bottom of the frame :-)

Comment: I don't get a scrollbar?

Comment: I'am so sorry, go to denis.dk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `iframe` displays a scrollbar because it your content is vertically larger than its default height. In Chrome, the default height appears to be 150px, but it could be anything. An `iframe` doesn't automatically size to its content.

I question the use of an `iframe` at all. It should probably be a part of the main page; if it needs to be dynamic, use AJAX or compose the page server-side.

Also note that the `<center>` tag used multiple times on the page is deprecated. Use CSS instead.

Comment: I found iframe the most easy solution :-)

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to accomplish. You might update your question to state the problem you are trying to solve (e.g. loading content dynamically, scrolling large content, etc.)

Comment: I have updated the question, or have i misunderstood something? :-) Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: if iframe is the easy solution for you, you have bigger problems then the scroll. using outdated technology, which is not advised in good practices, is kind of.. lame.

Comment: @Dementic - calling someone lame isn't constructive; pointing them to good practices/information would be more useful. Everyone has to start somewhere.

Comment: @TimMedora - sorry, but i was not calling you lame, i was talking about the method you choose. if you were googling a bit, you would have find out by yourself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/are-iframes-considered-bad-practice