# How to embed other websites via iframe / ahref?

Tags: html, iframe

I have html site - i would like to do the following

```
-----------------------------
Link1 website1     | 
Link2 website2     | Mysite
Link3 website3     |
-----------------------------
```

As you can see, on right side, content will be 
static - Its from my website.

On left side there is 3 links (a href) - which point to
three different domain.

Now how to ensure, when I click on link1, website1 content displayed

```
---------------------------------
            | 
Website1    | Mysite
            |
---------------------------------
```

If link2 clicked, Website2 content will be displayed.

bonus question : Embedding other site like this way , cause any security
threat to my site?

google gave me this :

[see here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe_name)

but its little different from my requirement

Comment: So you want an `iFrame` that changes source when one of the `href`'s is clicked?

Comment: Embedding others sites is traditionally done by using `<iframe>`'s. However, this has been a *no go* for some time now (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/are-iframes-considered-bad-practice). Why do you want to do this instead of opening a new browser window?

Comment: @ Mattios550, Yes, that's right. iframe content changes when href is clicked.

Comment: @ Erik Schierboom, thanks for the link. I prefer not open a new window. I'll read about them and decide on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should first give your iframe a name, then target your links to that iframe

## Example:

```
<iframe src="external.htm" name="iframe"></iframe>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="iframe">SO</a>
```

**References:**

- The name section here: [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)
- The target section here: [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)
- "Use iframe as a Target for a Link" section here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp

Comment: Cute - I've never played with the `target` attribute on `a` elements much and had no idea this was possible. I was expecting that to do this you would need to change the `src` attribute (or analagous property) of the iframe.

Comment: It  worked. I placed,  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="iframe">SO</a> inside external.html file. Thanks