# How to scope dynamically loaded html/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I may be thinking about this the wrong way, but what I'm trying to do is load a region of a single page web-app using something like Ajax or the jQuery `.load` function, but load it such that when the section loads, `this` does not refer to the entire global application scope, but rather just the segment that was loaded. Basically, I want the region to be able to manipulate itself, but not have any access to outside objects (at least not unintentionally).

Comment: That's what `<iframe>` elements are for.

Comment: Also: when you load your content, the *best* thing would be for it to have no `<script>` tags in it at all.  Ideally, all your scripts would be managed by the container page.

Comment: How would the loaded page communicate to the container page what scripts it wanted?

Comment: Well there are various ways you could do that. The containery framework could dynamically load services via some basic API, or else (depends on circumstance) the container could simply have available all services that any part of the site needs.

Comment: I would be careful with iFrames. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/are-iframes-considered-bad-practice for a discussion on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's `ajax(...)` method has a `context` parameter that you can use to specify what `this` will be within any of the callbacks.

To quote their documentation:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $(this).addClass("done");
});
```

See [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more details.

Comment: Oh, that's pretty useful. Thank you!

Comment: This is true and it's a good thing to know, but it won't really achieve what was asked for.

Comment: Well the OP is (I think) about how to constrain scripts (like, code in `<script>` tags) that arrive with dynamically-loaded page fragments.

Comment: I interpreted it having `this` to refer to something other than the `window` object, which I saw as the "global application scope" that was mentioned. With the approach above, you can specify any object you want, including the DOM element that will have it's HTML content replaced on an AJAX success callback. I guess we'd have to get some more clarification from the OP to see exactly what he's looking for here.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just trying to load a section of the page in sort of a 'sandboxed' mode, where the `this` object refers to the top level html element of the sandbox, rather than the entire `window`.