# Opening a link inside a website

Tags: php, html, iframe

My dad used to make websites and while looking through one, I noticed that while staying on the same address, he was able to display an external website, within that same page. He basically just had a sidebar and the rest was there to open the links in from the bar. I am trying to achieve a similar effect.

PS: I don't think he had to use any PHP, he did it back in like, 1998.

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking of [iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)? I believe those aren't very popular these days, though, and CSS+DOM manipulation tend to be used instead for changing content in specific sections of a page.

Comment: That sounds like frames.

Comment: Could I PHP include as a substitute.

Comment: You should read this on `iframe`s: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: @bblincoe W3Schools? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: @Hunter What would you be trying to achieve with the `include`?

Comment: @AlbertXing First thing that came up on google... :X

Comment: @Hunter As unpopular `iframe` is today, I'm sure in 1998 it was the best thing that happened to HTML

Comment: BTW, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/are-iframes-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @Albert Xing: No, you're thinking of the <marquee> tag. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can *include* a page into another one with `<iframe>` It'll produce a box inside your page and load the page requested in parallel. A simple [example can be found here.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe)
To make your own page, you just have to change the `iframe` line:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Your fancy web page</h1>

    <iframe src="http://cat-bounce.com/">
      <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

... will load a page with a title a page with some cat to bounce in a box. You can interact with both pages, but they can't shared object between them.
Also, **some websites doesn't support iframes** and will returns blank box, like StackOverflow, Google, etc.

Be aware this method is quite unpopular today.

Comment: Your example doesn't work, because stackoverflow doesn't support iframes. It will end up looking like this: http://imgur.com/1p7xtFD

Comment: Ohohoh. Nice to know, I'm going to change the example.

Answer (score 1):

The guide line of doing this nowadays:

1- Make an iframe in your page with the name attribute such as `<iframe name="myLinksWin"></iframe>`

2- In every link that you want it to be opened in this iframe you have to use the `target` attribute with value equals to the iframe name attribute `<a href="http://yahoo.com" target="myLinksWin">The link</a>`

However, I think in 1998 your dad, used `frameset`.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**
Use an [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe), which allows you to display content from other sources. However, not all websites will support this. Sites can easily detect if they are in an `iframe` by comparing `window.location` with `document.location`.

**Method 2**
Use AJAX to load parts of other pages (I'm not sure if this would work on all pages, though). It may cause problems if you need to load images/stylesheets/scripts on that page with a source defined relatively.

**Method 3**
Load pages from PHP using cURL. This will load any page, but it may cause problems if you need to load images/stylesheets/scripts on that page with a source defined relatively.

Comment: Could I do PHP include?

Comment: @Hunter I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Hunter PHP include what? PHP include is used for importing PHP code to use in the current script, not for getting websites

Comment: So I couldn't get a whole site?

Comment: @Hunter Yes, you can get the whole site, with any of the above methods. However, some sites have ways of preventing you from doing this (Google and Facebook, for example).

Comment: @cloudcoder2000 both 2 & 3 won't work with external stylesheets and javascript.

Comment: @AlbertXing Thanks for pointing out that about method 2. However, I think that it would be possible (although really complicated, and not worth the effort) to load the stylesheets/scripts as well, by going through each url and loading it separately.

Comment: @cloudcoder2000 That'd work, but I don't see how that would be more semantic than an `iframe` here, especially if you're loading external sites.

Comment: @AlbertXing It would work with sites that block iframes.