# Having same <div> on all my sites

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to create a site like any other. I want the "thing" at the top (home downloads and stuff) to be on all my pages. Do I need to copy and paste the same code over and over again?

Comment: What is your server side code? c# or java or php?

Comment: please mention the platform..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the common part in  your `header/some specific file` and use ,since you will be using `header/some specific file` on all pages so the desired content will also be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Learn [Psd to html conversion](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/from-psd-to-html-building-a-set-of-website-designs-step-by-step--net-37) For batter understanding the divs and styles modification and customization.. your divs and tags can be easily maintained with your stylesheet by giving id and classes you can also give one dive multiple classes and ids,

**you are talking about master page i think**
that is one in style and in that page you're showing other page, likely we can say one template page and many functionality  [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464326/how-to-create-a-master-page-using-html) and
[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532555/how-to-create-a-masterpage-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned pretty much all the intelligent options for solving this problem are mentioned [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464326/how-to-create-a-master-page-using-html?lq=1)

Use a server-side template (e.g.php), use a client-side template (e.g. handlebars), use javascript, or you could use a static site generator like Jekyll.