# Using JavaScript (only - no libraries) to load another page into div

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is the JavaScript equivalent of `$('content').load('page.html');` I am trying to load content in another page into my `div` but I cannot find a method for plain old JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good old JavaScript:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

```
var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();           //XMLHttpRequest is how you do it
myRequest.onreadystatechange = function(e){
    if(myRequest.readyState == 4 && myRequest.status == 200){
        var data = myRequest.responseText;               //returned data
        document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = data;  //not safe but whatever
    }
};
myRequest.open("get", "url here", true);
myRequest.send();
```

It is always better to do it with plain JavaScript first before using those fancy jQuery one-method-takes-care-of-everything-for-you methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has two parts:

1. Grabbing some content on a server from the client
2. Pushing that content into a div.

For part one, see this thread for instructions on using XMLHTTPRequest():

[HTTP GET request in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript)

For part two, as for populating the div, it's this simple:

```
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = 'someContent';
```

Note that you may want to scrub your content before populating the div depending on the source of the page you are requesting, as using JS to populate a div with raw HTML is an attack vector that hackers might try to exploit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried taking a look at using iframes? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: I thought about it but they're considered bad practice nowadays, aren't they?

Comment: It really depends on what situation you're using it for. Could you go into more detail on what type of content you're trying to load? Is it just from another page within your domain? Do you care about CSS?

Comment: @Spike - It can be good or bad depending on how you use it. There is a question on SO discussed this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/are-iframes-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 0):

It's called an XML HTTP Request (XHR). See the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the source code [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/load.js), jQuery's `load()` function calls the `ajax()` function to load the external html.

Under the hood, the `ajax()` function uses [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) which is how you would retrieve the file using vanilla JavaScript.