# Iframe does not work correctly in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, iframe

I have a ASP.Net Web form application project.
I use Google iframe but it does not work.
Please help me.
My code:

```
Location="https://www.google.com/maps/place/%D8%B4%D8%B1%DA%A9%D8%AA+%D8%AC%D9%87%D8%A7%D9%86+%D8%B4%DB%8C%D9%85%DB%8C+%D8%A8%D8%B3%D9%BE%D8%A7%D8%B1%E2%80%AD/@35.7743752,51.3679948,14z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sjahan+shimi+baspar!3m4!1s0x0:0x9f32a31df4793a64!8m2!3d35.7721173!4d51.3661373"
    <iframe width="100%" height="400px" scrolling="no" 
src="location"></iframe>
```

Comment: you need to use the google embeded maps api

Comment: Please. So please, don't use iframe. I'm sure you can solve it somehow without iframe. use javascript/jquery/bootstrap/... but not iframe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178505/good-reasons-why-not-to-use-iframes-in-page-content

Answer (score 0):

Just use google's provided embed code:

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d25896.326046334627!2d51.3679948!3d35.7743752!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x9f32a31df4793a64!2z2LTYsdqp2Kog2KzZh9in2YYg2LTbjNmF24wg2KjYs9m-2KfYsQ!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1473145596653" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `src="location"` doesn't automatically read some "location" variable/parameter/whatever, it just tries to use the value `"location"` as url and fails.

So you need to use some way to inject the contents of your `Location` variable as value of `src`.

How to do that depends on how you generate that HTML:

For webforms you may need something like `src="<%= Location %>"`.
For MVC it will be something like `src="@Location"`.