# link session in php loaded in single frame

Tags: javascript, php, html, session, iframe

I need to do when a link is clicked then it is opened in same frame where from it is opened.

Means, I have **index.php** file and it has one iframe **FrameLoader**

```
<div class='iframebox'>
<?php
if(empty($_GET['p'])){
   $_SESSION['iFrameLoader']='home.php';
}else{
   $_SESSION['iFrameLoader']=$_GET['p'].".php";
}
?>
    <iframe src="<?php echo $_SESSION['iFrameLoader']; ?>" name="iFrameLocate" id="iFrameLocate"></iframe>
    </div>
```

And there is three other php files, home.php, demo1.php and demo2.php

home.php

```
<h1>This is home page for demo</h1>
<a href='index.php?p=demo1'>Page 1</a>
<a href='index.php?p=demo2'>Page 2</a>
```

It open in same frame but also create index.php inside of index.php. so how to fix this for open in same frame other sub pages and with similar layouts.

Comment: Maybe you can try this: [How to force link from iframe to be opened in the parent window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037839/how-to-force-link-from-iframe-to-be-opened-in-the-parent-window)

Answer (score 0):

I would personally avoid using iframe. [Good Reasons why not to use Iframes in page content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178505/good-reasons-why-not-to-use-iframes-in-page-content)