# I want to embed youtube video and also show gallery/playlist

Tags: javascript, web, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I want to show in a gallery all of the videos from our youtube channel. I am using `<iframe>` but it is only showing one video. How can I show all of the viedos from our channel?

```
<div>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Wyq6YeoM2ZA?ecver=2" width="640" height="360" frameborder="5" style="position:absolute;width:70%;height:60%;left:15%" allowfullscreen playlist></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use the iframe HTML tag? You might want to read about why it's considered bad here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178505/good-reasons-why-not-to-use-iframes-in-page-content#23178537

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read the guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This HTML will embed a player that will show all of your videos. Replace YOURCHANNELNAME with your channel name.

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=user_uploads&list=YOURCHANNELNAME" width="480" height="400"></iframe>
```

Comment: not working???
would you please tell me  **YOURCHANNELNAME ** just simple name or something???

Comment: See  the following link for more details. https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3250431?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You can watch in Youtube API. It is documented well in several progamming languagues. Here is a snippet in javascript:

```
// Sample js code for playlists.list

// See full sample for buildApiRequest() code, which is not 
// specific to a particular youtube or youtube method.

buildApiRequest('GET',
                '/youtube/v3/playlists',
                {'channelId': 'UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw',
                 'maxResults': '25',
                 'part': 'snippet,contentDetails'});
```

More on https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list.

Comment: i read document it's complex as i already mention i am learning so i guess it's little hard for me now. 
is there anyother way to complete ?