# HTML code set as src in iframe not showing in IE 11

Tags: html, iframe, internet-explorer-11

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id='smartPartFrame' src='data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<h1>inteGREAT</h1>' scrolling='no' width='1000px' height='70px'></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

The above html code used to show h1 in iframe. Chrome, Firefox, Edge working fine. IE 11 is showing the error: the page cannot be displayed. I wants to set html directly in src not file path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [page is not loading inside the iframe in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695191/page-is-not-loading-inside-the-iframe-in-ie11)

Comment: @JaxCze: That question doesn't involve data URIs. The only thing it has in common with this question is that something in iframes doesn't work in Internet Explorer 11.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 11 does not support data URIs in iframes, nor any other way to embed HTML inline in an iframe.

The "intended" way to do this in the standard is with the `srcdoc` attribute, not the `src` attribute given a data URI, but [browser support for `srcdoc` remains poor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593515/is-it-bad-practise-to-use-iframes-can-iframes-be-translated-into-images-in-the/24593787#24593787).