# Using a button inside an iframe to reload a div outside the iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have:

```
<script>
var btn = document.getElementById("doReload");
btn.onclick = function(){

    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#div1").load("News.php");
    }, 5000);
}

</script>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image" />
<input id="doReload" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

All of this is loaded in an iframe using src=, When I click the submit button i want it to do a file upload (Which it currently does), then i would like it to reload News.php into Div1 to show the updated file, any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You might need to reload the whole page... Use `top.location.replace("http://example.com/");` to do that.

Comment: @TRGWII I can't i load a index page and a user presses a button that loads content into that page, I just need to be able to reload that content

Comment: Just run the same function you used to load the initial content?

Comment: Also, do you absolutely need to use frames? http://stackoverflow.com/q/362730/

Comment: @TRGWII I would prefer to so i do not need to reload the page

Comment: I think I see the problem now, gonna make an answer

Comment: Ok, http://crapaudhall.com/admin/ this may help, I am working under the news button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the problem is that your form is submitting before the timeout executes the function.

You should use jQuery to submit the form ([jQuery submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)) with event.preventDefault() to stop the submit-button from actually reloading the page.

this can be done by changing the code like so:

```js
document.getElementById("doReload").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = this.parentElement;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(form.method, form.action);
  xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) $("#div1").load("News.php");
  })
  xhr.send(new FormData(form));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="upload/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="image" />
  <input id="doReload" type="submit" />
</form>
```

(Solved on chat with some other small modifications, this was the final working code though)

Comment: That does not appear to work? Can you see if i did something wrong?

Comment: Eh, I tested the upload functionality a bit... :P

Comment: Still doesn't appear to work? Although it should i think, not sure what the issue is? Does anyone see it?

Comment: You can delete what you upload right there. Its a content editable div, simply delete the pictures from the div and then hit Save.

Comment: Try now, you still put the script before the html :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71123/discussion-between-mark-shaw-and-trgwii).

Answer (score 1):

In order to trigger `#doReload`'s click callback, try putting your script after the markup:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image" />
<input id="doReload" type="submit"/>
</form>
<script>
var btn = document.getElementById("doReload");
btn.onclick = function(){

    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#div1").load("News.php");
    }, 5000);
}

</script>
```

or wrapping it in `$( document ).ready(function() { ... });`

But since (afaik) there isn't a callback on html form submission success, you may want to do the post using jQuery's `$.post` and then use its `success` callback to retrieve the new data.