# Embed external website in Rails template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a Rails site and an externally hosted WordPress blog. I want to be able to send users to mysite.com/blog and have them hit the blog. I can do that pretty easily with a redirect. But then they are no longer on my main site.

What I really want is to render the blog inside my main template, so that the navbar from my site remains on the page, and the url stays as mysite.com/blog. Ideally, when they clicked on a link in the blog, it would render inside the template, but the navbar and url from the rails site would remain intact.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this. Some examples:

1. [Iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) come to mind first. Frowned upon in modern web development, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/are-iframes-considered-bad-practice) for lots of reasons, but is probably the simplest way.
2. Jquery [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/), or just a basic ajax call. Note that because of the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), it won't work if you're trying to retrieve from another domain. A workaround would be to include something like this in your Wordpress site to explicitly allow requests from your Rails site:

   `<customHeaders>
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://your-rails-site.com" />
   </customHeaders>`
3. [HTML imports](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/)

There are some other ways including but not limited to `<object>` and `<embed>` tags. I would suggest to research them and find the best solution for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I actually found what may be a more ideal solution. Since I'm linking to a WordPress site, it looks like it is possible to set up the blog in a subdirectory and incorporate it into the rails router. I'm going to test this idea out and see if it works. Also seems more optimal for SEO purposes. Here's [the blog post](http://rywalker.com/setting-up-a-wordpress-blog-on-heroku-as-a-subdirectory-of-a-rails-app-also-hosted-on-heroku/) that outlines the process.