# Is there any way to play you tube video on my web page without using iframe tag

Tags: iframe

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/iO26ikYDquo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

i dont want to use iframe tag due to resons mentioned in [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/are-iframes-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use **object** or **embed**

Example object:

```
<object width="420" height="315"
data="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</object>
```

Example embed:

```
<embed width="420" height="315"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
```

Visit [HTML YouTube Videos](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp) for more information

[image]

Comment: will you please tell me for browser support

Comment: Visit this page for tag embed: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_embed.asp