# Including directory and keep it working php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter and facing the following problem.

In a controller, I want to include in some way an application (Not written in Codeigniter) in my controller. I am using file_get_contents now. It's working fine and the application is shown in the controller I made. The problem is, the application contains a lot of forms which are posted to other pages in the application itself. Using file_get_contents, the forms redirect the user to a target outside my controller. This may sound a bit vague, so here's an example:

> The user navigates to the controller: 'game/login' and therefore wants
>   to visit the login page. The user fills in the form. The form posts
>   the data to assets/game/index.php?page=login. This makes the user
>   redirect to assets/game/index.php?page=login, and therefore making him
>   leave the controller page.

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this problem?

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Game extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct(); 
    }


    public function index($page = ''){  
        file_get_contents(FCPATH . 'assets/game/index.php?page=' . $page);
    }

}
```

Comment: Its not a good idea but you can load your external `php` pages in a iframe

Comment: @Zeeshan Why is that not a good idea?

Comment: I am talking about you should convert your php files to codeigniter MVC structure to get the advantages.Also there will be some problems. You can check this link if it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/are-iframes-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @Zeeshan True, it should be converted. But is there no way around this except for using the iFrame? Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: No,the quick way is iframe only..

Comment: @Zeeshan Then I'll use the iFrame, thanks for the answer.

Comment: ok..I am posting it as answer,Kindly accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load your external php pages in a iframe but i would suggest you should convert your php files to codeigniter MVC structure to get the advantages.

The quick way is using iframe,but i would ask you to refer this post to get an idea on Iframes when to use & when not to.
[Are iframes considered 'bad practice'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/are-iframes-considered-bad-practice)