# want to display these folders from Index of to my html page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, xampp

I want to display these folders in my html page. when I click on the Go PVP it goes to other page called Index of /new-l/GO PVP . but I want to display it on the right corner.

[The image when I click on the Go PVP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib8AL.png)
[The image when I click on the Go PVP that comes to this page that I don't want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt97H.png)
[The image where I want to it show the folders when I click on the Go PVP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZPfe.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>HELLO WORLD</title>

    <!-- CSS File -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome Cdn Link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css"/>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="GO PVP/">
              <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
              <span class="nav-item">Go PVP</span>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">
              <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
              <span class="nav-item">Profile</span>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">
              <i class="fas fa-wallet"></i>
              <span class="nav-item">Wallet</span>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">
              <i class="fas fa-chart-bar"></i>
              <span class="nav-item">Analytics</span>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">
              <i class="fas fa-tasks"></i>
              <span class="nav-item">Tasks</span>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">
              <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
              <span class="nav-item">Settings</span>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">
              <i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i>
              <span class="nav-item">Help</span>
            </a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
  <!--  Javascript File -->
  <script src="assets/index.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I want to see these folders on my html page at the right corner.

Comment: You can try [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.ASP) which will do the work. Also check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/are-iframes-considered-bad-practice